# Remove simple emoji python

Tags: python, emoji

how can I remove emoji in text like this:

```
'ca va toi ;-) ?'
```

I used many solution about removing emoji but nothing work. 
I want output like this:

```
ca va toi ?
```

I don't want to remove punctuation but only those thats form emojis.
Thanks

Comment: That's what used to be called an emoticon.

Comment: Have fun parsing `I watched tv last night (until 8)` where some forums say, "hey, I see cool shades there "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you. You can add additional rules to make it generalize better.

```
x = 'ca va toi ;-) ?'

x = x.replace(';-)', '')
x = x.replace(';-(', '')
x = x.replace(';-|', '')
x = x.replace(';-D', '')
```

> 'ca va toi  ?'

If you want to clean out all punctuation as well you can do the following

```
x = 'ca va toi ;-) ?'

''.join([i for i in x if (i >= 'a' and i<='z') or (i >= 'A' and i<='Z') or i == ' ')
```

> 'ca va toi  '

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do it is to specify a list of possible emojis.

```
emoji_list = [";-)", ":)"]
```

And then remove occurrences of those strings in your string.

```
# A dictionary with your emojis or any combination of characters you want to get rid of.
emoji_list = [";-)", ":)"]

# Your input string
string = 'ca va :) toi ;-) ?'

# Split the string into a list of substrings.
string_list = string.split()

# Using list comprehension, create a new list that excludes the emoji_list items.
clear_string = [string for string in string_list if string not in emoji_list]

# ALTERNATIVE a cleaner way is to use higher-order function filter to filter out the emojis.
clear_string = filter(lambda x: x not in emoji_list, string_list)

# Join the list into a string again.
output = " ".join(clear_string)

print(output)
```

You can make use of the list comprehension in python to create a list that excludes the substrings defined in `emoji_list`. Another way is to use the higher-order function `filter` to filter out those emojis.

You are then left with a new list that excludes those substrings you defined in `emoji_list` and then you are simply joining the list to a string to get your desired result.

**Note:** This is a very simple approach that can easily return a false positive (i.e a substring treated as emoji which in reality is not). These assumptions or cases are not covered by this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tested the code but when I have text like this: 'Hello , :(you look happy!' It can't find the ':(' .

Comment: @mee As I said this solution cannot deal with such cases. There is a way around it but will cause other problems as well. If you fix this problem then this one will break: `Hello, I am attaching the files:(python script and text file)`. If you fix your case how would you avoid this one?